# PEAR mail, using web form to get $to

Tags: php, email, pear

I am trying to switch a webpage from regular PHP mail to PEAR mail. On this page I want the email sent to a recipient who is entering their email into a web form. I am trying to set the $to equal to $pickeremail, as per the code below, but alas, then PEAR tries to send the email to "$pickeremail" rather than to the email that is actually entered in the web form by the user.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","BLAHBLAH","BLAHBLAH");

mysql_select_db("schoolh_SHS", $con);

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql      = "UPDATE Donations SET `PICKER_NAME`='$_POST[pickername]',`PICKER_EMAIL`='$_POST[pickeremail]',`PICKER_PHONE`='$_POST[pickerphone]',`STATUS`='CLAIMED' WHERE DONATIONID = $_POST[id]";
$q        = "SELECT * FROM Donations WHERE DONATIONID = $_POST[id]";
$result   = mysql_query($q);
$Donation = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$orgname     = mysql_result($result,$i,"orgname");
$address     = mysql_result($result,$i,"address");
$city        = mysql_result($result,$i,"city");
$state       = mysql_result($result,$i,"state");
$pickeremail = mysql_result($result,$i,"picker_email");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

function send_email($recipients, $from, $subject, $body)
{
  require_once "Mail.php";
  require_once "Mail/mime.php";

  $to         = '$pickeremail';
  $cc         = 'whynoceros@gmail.com';
  $recipients = $to.", ".$cc;
  $subject    = 'Pickup Confirmation';
  $from       = 'blah';
  $host       = 'blah';
  $username   = 'donations';
  $password   = 'blahblah';

  $headers = array (
    'From'    => $from,
    'To'      => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
  );

  $mime = new Mail_mime();
  $mime->setHTMLBody($body);

  $body = $mime->get();
  $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host'     => $host, 
    'auth'     => true,
    'username' => $username, 
    'password' => $password
  ));
  $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

  if (PEAR::isError($mail))
  {
    //return false;
    echo ($mail->getMessage());
  } 
  else 
  {
    return true; 
  }
}
```

I added a var_dump, as per the suggestion below, out was:

> array(6) { ["MIME-Version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["Content-Type"]=> string(29) "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" ["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]=> string(16) "quoted-printable" ["From"]=> string(33) "donations@schoolhousesupplies.org" ["To"]=> string(0) "" ["Subject"]=> string(19) "Pickup Confirmation" } Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 501, response: 5.5.4 Invalid Address)]NULL

I noticed that in the header array I had 'To'      => $to, I changed this to 'To' => $recipients. I also changed the line: $pickeremail = mysql_result($result,$i,"picker_email");  to:$pickeremail=$_POST['pickeremail']; Now, I am getting the this var_dump: array(6) { ["MIME-Version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["Content-Type"]=> string(29) "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" ["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]=> string(16) "quoted-printable" ["From"]=> string(33) "donations@schoolhousesupplies.org" ["To"]=> string(20) "whynoceros@gmail.com" ["Subject"]=> string(19) "Pickup Confirmation" } Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 501, response: 5.5.4 Invalid Address)]NULL

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong here:

```
$to         = '$pickeremail';
```

Because when using simple quote, the php variable inside won't be interpreted. Replace this line with :

```
$to = $pickeremail;
```

**edit:**

Look at the dump:

> ["To"]=> string(0) ""

You put an empty string into `$to`. So it's seems that your `picker_email` field is empty in your database. You should check it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had tried that and when I do, I get the following error: Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 501, response: 5.5.4 Invalid Address)]

Comment: Put a `var_dump($headers);` in paste the output in your question

Comment: Thank j0k, I made sure there was a value in picker_email and still I get the same output. Is there a way for me to do directly from the $_POST[pickeremail] to the $to ?

Comment: Well yes. Instead of `$pickeremail = mysql_result($result,$i,"picker_email");` use `$pickeremail = $_POST[pickername]`. By the way, where did you execute the `$sql`? Because it seems that this query update the email you try to retrieve after.